# sharepoint workflow mandatory fields

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-workflow, custom-lists

I am new to Sharepoint.

I have created a custom list with certain mandatory fields. The list contains end user personal information. In the beginning of workflow process, the receptionist will enter end user name and email address in the fields of the list. The list will be sent to end user to fill up his information.

Is it possible for the receptionist bypass the mandatory fields in the list?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

No, you would need to make these optional within the SPList and enforce them elsewhere. I would handle this within the workflow or form. If the user misses information the form itself would enforce it (not the list), or the workflow would send them a notification prompting them to enter further data.

Comment: how can i enforce it on the form?